# Magento 2 .Woff blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: magento2, nginx, cloudfront-cdn

Have a Magento 2.3 on Nginx. Trying to set up Cloudfront for /pub/static/ on subdomain like https://static.mydomain.com.

Base URL for Static View Files is https://static.mydomain.com.
Getting error for all files .woff:

```
Access to font at has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Get net::ERR_FAILED
```

Ngnix magento settings for /static/

```
location /static/ {
location ~ ^/static/version {
    rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static/$2 last;
}

location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
    etag on;
    if_modified_since exact;
    add_header Pragma "public";
    add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public";
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS' always;
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,Authorization,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,Origin,Referer,X-HTTP-Method-Override,X-Accept-Charset,X-Accept,Accept,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type' always;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    expires +1y;

    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/static/?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$1 last;
    }
}

location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
    add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    expires    off;

    if (!-f $request_filename) {
       rewrite ^/static/?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$1 last;
    }
}

if (!-f $request_filename) {
    rewrite ^/static/?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$1 last;
}

add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
```

}

Still doesnt work. What Am I doing wrong here? Thanks

Comment: Is this the Cloudfront worker that's claiming a CORS error, or is this when you visit your site the Cloudfront served resources are generating this error?

Comment: @Brett I see error when I visit my site im not sure how to check what you are asking about

Comment: If Magento is configured to use the CDN for its resources (e.g. static.mysite.com) and not Magento itself (e.g. www.mysite.com), then you need to configure Cloudfront correctly to pass the appropriate CORS headers. See the AWS documentation on this exact error: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/no-access-control-allow-origin-error/

Comment: @Brett Still showing error, Im not an expert in Cloudfront but I did everything according to books...here is a website dscbalances.com please take a look, maybe you would have an idea.

Comment: @Brett by the way just noticed that fonts shows on website in Safari but not Chrome

Comment: Chrome has a more strict CORS implementation than Safari currently. Odds are Firefox would work too. The site you put doesn't work (at least I can't reach it).

Comment: @Brett weird that it doesnt it should redirect you to https://www.dscbalances.com

Comment: @OlgaBautina is it fixed?? I am facing same issue.

Comment: @ArsalanUlHaq no, still not fixed, I ended up disconnecting cdn for now.